# One picture box shown many times in the same form

Tags: vb.net, image

My Goal is to create a maze in VS using VB.net, I currently have managed to make a random Generator that makes the "maze" and shows the location of the last wall made.

```
    Horizontalwalls = Randomizer.Next(60, 91) 'Makes 60 - 90 Horizontal Walls
    VirticalWalls = Randomizer.Next(60, 91) 'Makes 60 -90 Vertical Walls
    Dim HLoops = 0 'counter for Horizontal walls
    Dim VLoops = 0
    lbxHorizontal.Items.Clear() 'empties the list box i have which stores the walls location
    lbxvertical.Items.Clear()
    Do While HLoops < (Horizontalwalls)
        HLoops += 1 'adds to the counter
        lbxHorizontal.Items.Insert(0, Randomizer.Next(0, 10))
        lbxHorizontal.Items.Insert(0, Randomizer.Next(0, 10))

        'Attempt at making visable walls
        pbxhorizontalwall.Top = (lbxHorizontal.Items.Item(0) * GridSize - 2) 'This and next line puts the wall in desired location
        pbxhorizontalwall.Left = (lbxHorizontal.Items.Item(1) * GridSize - 2)
    Loop
```

however the only way i know to make all the walls visible is to make 90 horizontal wall pictures, go though naming them all, then GLaaa... there must be a easier way to copy the same image over the screen at the desired location.

At the moment, all i really want to know is the line of code that will copy the image (and maybe a way to mass clear them all when the maze is reset) and then i'll work out how to get it into place...

Comment: You want the image to be drawn on the form?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You could create a `list` of pictures using a loop.

Comment: Are your tiles all the same size? If so you could create a Image that is the size of the area that you are needing to cover, draw your individual images to the larger image then assign it either to the Form's BackGroundImage Property

Comment: not necessarily on the form but to at least be visible to the player... and while they are all the same size there is 60+ and randomly generated... and if there's a way to have them drawn on a image and that being used as the background during runtime that could work, but what is the coding for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first create the list of images with:

```
Dim imageList As New List(Of Bitmap)

imageList.Add("image to add") 'do it for all the images you have
```

Then create a bitmap:

```
Dim bitmapWall as Bitmap = New Bitmap(widthOfbitmap, heightofbitmap, Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
```

Draw the list of images to the bimap:

```
    Dim objGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapWall)

    For i = 0 To imageList.Count
        objGraphics.DrawImage(imageList(i), x, y, imageList(i).Width, imageList(i).Height)
    Next

    objGraphics.Dispose()
```

x,y is the coordinates of where your images are drawn (you should change them for every iteration)

Lastly:

```
Me.BackgroundImage = bitmapWall
Me.Invalidate()
```

Dont forget to dispose the list and the bitmap in the end.

valter